# Saving and loading multiple strings to a UITextView in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitextfield

I'm working on an app that's a bit like a notebook of typed pages.

I have a `UITextView *documentText` and an `int currentPage` to keep track of multiple pages. Back and forward buttons add 1 or subtract 1 from `currentPage` and then they set the text in `documentText` to match the new value of `currentPage`.

However, when I run it, nothing saves, there's just a blank text field. I think it's a problem with `[saveDocs writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:NULL];`
 , but I'm not sure what to change, or if that's even the problem.

Anyways, here's the code I'm using to save the text:

```
- (IBAction)saveDocs:(id)sender {

NSString *saveDocs = documentText.text;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@-%d.txt", @"document", currentPage]];
[saveDocs writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:NULL];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:currentPage forKey:@"CurrentDocument"];


}
```

Also, in ViewDidLoad, I'm using this code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);

   currentPage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"CurrentDocument"];

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@-%d.txt", @"document", currentPage]];
NSString* doc = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[documentText setText:doc];
```

Thanks for your help,
-Karl

Comment: Are you actually **reloading** the view for every page?

Comment: Nope, I'm just resetting the textView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write with NSUnicodeStringEncoding.  But you read with NSUTF8StringEncoding.  Perhaps you should stick with NSUTF8StringEncoding for both writing and reading.